# Manuall install for language pack Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

I have Windows 10 1903 and I copied langage pack file

> Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package_ar-sa~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ar-sa~.esd
>
> ( SHA-1: 02a8a9a748d0f6213ab36b0ad2771901917c573d )

from **SoftwareDistribution** folder

Is there any way I can install it on other machine without downloading the package again?

Answer (score 0):

it works like magic

> `dism /online /Add-Package /Packagepath:Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package_ar-sa~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ar-sa~.esd`